# Where should I look for detailed exception information about why yarn application terminated in hadoop-2.5.2

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am now running a yarn application through a Hadoop cluster. The github address of the example yarn application is

https://github.com/blrunner/yarn-beginners-examples

However, if I submit the application and I can see the log ERROR like below

examples.MyClient: Application failed to complete successfully

Where should I look for detailed exception information about why an application terminated for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

When you launch YARN application from command line, you usually get the tracking URL on the command line.

You may also do:

```
yarn application -list
```

To get the list of applications and then do:

```
yarn application -status <ApplicationId>
```

to find status of your application.

---

Alternatively you may goto the YARN Resource manager UI and check your job status. YARN Resource Manager WebUI is usually port 8088. (from a browser goto `http://<server_ip>:8088`)

Answer (score 0):

For logs in Yarn,you have to check with Application id.You can check the status of applications with below:

```
yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING
```

If you are aware of the application id,then to check the logs you can use below:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>
```